# EXCEL: Average Rank of list with sumproduct or rank.avg?

Tags: excel

e.g. I have a list

```
 A    B    C    D    E..
 Name avg  sec  sec
 x1    ?   3    2
 x2        5    1
 x3        7    3
 ..
```

is it possivle with sumproduct oder rank.avg find out the avg rank from the columns C..D?
player x1 has in column C place 1 and in col D place 2 => in avg = 1.5

- x1   1.5
- x2   1.5
- x3   3

Answer (score 0):

You can try below formula

```
=(RANK.EQ(C2,$C$2:$C$4,1)+RANK.EQ(D2,$D$2:$D$4,1))/2
```

[image]

Comment: when i want to get the avg from e.g. 20 cols, i dont want to sum 20 ranks and div by 20

Comment: Then how you will calculate avg from 20 cols? Do you want result in single cell?

Comment: Yes, in a single cell. I dont want do adapt my formula, when I add a new col with ranks.